# "desSerialize" data en PHP

Tags: php, jquery

estoy enviando data de un formulario el cual tiene muchos checkbox que comparten el mismo name , quiero enviar esos valores, lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
var dataform= ($('input[name="cnSelects"]:checked').serialize());
 $.ajax({
              data: {"data":dataform},
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "asset/query/q_showfieldstomake.php",
                    success: function (data)
                    {
            alert(data);
                    }
                });
```

y cuando los recibo llegan así:

```
'cnSelects=name-c-cn&cnSelects=lname1-c-cn&cnSelects=lname2-c-cn&cnSelects=fnacimiento-c-cn&cnSelects=telfijo-c-cn&cnSelects=telmovil-c-cn&cnSelects=email-c-cn&cnSelects=otraact-c-cn&cnSelects=cualotraact-c-cn'
```

Cómo hago en php para "desSerialziarlo", siempre he usado esta función:

```
parse_str($_POST['data'], $searcharray);
foreach($searcharray as $nombre_campo => $valor){ 
                       $asignacion = "\$" . $nombre_campo . "='" . $valor . "';"; 
                           eval($asignacion);
          echo $asignacion."  "."<br>";
                    }
//esta funcion hace que cada name del formulario se combierta en una variable  con su respectivo valor              
}
```

pero aqui no me funciona porque toda la data llega con un mismo  name. y quiero tener cada valor independientemente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que poner corchetes `[]` en tus `<inputs name="cnSelects[]">` para que tengas este resultado:

`cnSelects[]=name-c-cn&cnSelects[]=lname1-c-cn&cnSelects[]=lname2-c-cn ........`

Y luego puedes hacer las nuevas variables de esta forma:

```
parse_str($_POST['data'], $searcharray);

$i = 1;

foreach($searcharray as $nombre_campo) {

    foreach($nombre_campo as $valor) {

        $variable = key($searcharray).$i; // Pasamos nombre "cnSelects" y numero del $i

        $asignacion = "\$" . $variable . "='" . $valor . "';";
        eval($asignacion);
        $i++;
    }
}

echo $cnSelects1; // name-c-cn
echo $cnSelects2; // lname1-c-cn
...
```

[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/989f98abf445c87f23c5bc688494397c79192af2)

Comment: Gracias, funcionó perfecto!.